# How can I fetch the URL using regular expression (looked into a few answers from SO but that doesn't solved my problem)?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to fetch all the web addresses mentioned in a .txt file. Even though I was able to do for few of the addresses but some which are enclosed inside a parenthesis are getting fetched with some unwanted text.

This is an excerpt from my file:

```
Details: http://www.source.sakaiproject.org/viewsvn/?view=rev&rev=39772

Author: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
Date: 2008-01-05 09:12:07 -0500 (Sat, 05 Jan 2008)
New Revision: 39772

Modified:
content/branches/sakai_2-5-x/content-impl/impl/src/java/org/sakaiproject/content/impl/ContentServiceSqlOracle.java
content/branches/sakai_2-5-x/content-impl/impl/src/java/org/sakaiproject/content/impl/DbContentService.java
Log:
SAK-12501 merge to 2-5-x: r39622, r39624:5, r39632:3 (resolve conflict from differing linebreaks for r39622)

----------------------
This automatic notification message was sent by Sakai Collab (https://collab.sakaiproject.org/portal) from the Source site.
You can modify how you receive notifications at My Workspace > Preferences.

Details: http://source.sakaiproject.org/viewsvn/?view=rev&rev=39771

Author: louis@media.berkeley.edu
Date: 2008-01-04 18:08:50 -0500 (Fri, 04 Jan 2008)
New Revision: 39771

Modified:
bspace/site-manage/sakai_2-4-x/site-manage-tool/tool/src/bundle/sitesetupgeneric.properties
bspace/site-manage/sakai_2-4-x/site-manage-tool/tool/src/java/org/sakaiproject/site/tool/SiteAction.java
Log:
BSP-1415 New (Guest) user Notification

----------------------
This automatic notification message was sent by Sakai Collab (https://collab.sakaiproject.org/portal) from the Source site.
You can modify how you receive notifications at My Workspace > Preferences.
```

I used this regex: `https?://(www\.)?.+` to capture the addresses and tried on Atom editor.

Here is the result of it.
[image]

I'm confused about what could I possibly do to catch that URL enclosed inside parenthesis along without any conflict with rest of the URLs. Can someone from the SO community please assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude matching a `)` and match only non whitespace chars

```
https?://[^\s)]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PSyFmp/1)

If there can be only an `)` at the end, you might also use a capture group and match an optional `)` followed by a whitespace boundary

```
(https?://\S+?)\)?(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b28f86/1)

---

With a word boundary, and without the capture group you can use

```
\bhttps?://\S+\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HoUwDQ/1)

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `https?://` Match the protocol with optional `s` and `://`
  = `\S+` match 1+ times a non whitespace char
- `\b` A word boundary

Comment: I understand the situation and I also had came up with a similar solution. But since we have seen that there are a few URLs enclosed inside ( ). Considering a situation that there is just a couple of URLs mentioned inside the file and this file has huge amount of text data, then high chances of missing such web addresses!

Comment: @AdarshNamdev Do the patterns give you the desired result?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get you!!

Comment: @AdarshNamdev Reading your comment, I did not understand if the patterns work for you. Are they ok?

Comment: Yes, your pattern gave me the desired result. good news is that I tweaked your first pattern: 
\bhttps?://(www\.)?[^\s]+\b

This one also worked. The second pattern you gave fetched the ")" as well

Comment: @AdarshNamdev You can use that pattern, but the word boundary at the end might not match the whole string. Also you can omit the capture group `(www\.)?` if you don't need to process the group value afterwards as `\S` matches also `www.` Then you can shorten the pattern to `\bhttps?://\S+\b` See https://regex101.com/r/HoUwDQ/1 The pattern with the capture group `(https?://\S+?)\)?(?!\S)` matches the `)` at the end, but as you can see in the demo link https://regex101.com/r/b28f86/1 the part that you want is in group 1, which is highlighted in green and can be accessed  using `$1` or `\1`

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird for your help your pattern ```\bhttps?://\S+\b``` solved my problem . For the regex "Grouping" , I am not much aware of them for now but will read about it and practice using those too.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
\bhttps?://(?:www\.)?\S+\b
```

See  [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/LxHbIJ/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  s?                       's' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ://                      '://'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    www                      'www'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

[**Python code**](https://tio.run/##ZZBBa4RADIXv/orgoSgtI3QPSwXrpddCYQ@lMFDG2bhOVyeSyWr99XaU9tRDIIQv7yVvXKQjf1hXN4zEAowJ4wW/oQJOddOJjKEuiyKry3metcprfbrXTZoIBvkMwhFMX1CM60MJGx7hSKpAN7aogrkaNzJ9oRVFfCkmh3OYfFFvTcU43cWqDk/H46P22e4XFSz1vWn@b283mj6HlmkA6RBOuw0EJ6i0/6AbWONhoLNrF@hohiWOGC26CcGTuNZZI458ACPwusA78TWMJmo8wxtji4zeYlBpMhixHYYtCVSt82fT99kezgP8fZ8nIzsvkP3C@br@AA):

```py
import re
regex = r"\bhttps?://(?:www\.)?\S+\b"
test_str = "Details: http://www.source.sakaiproject.org/viewsvn/?view=rev&rev=39772\n(https://collab.sakaiproject.org/portal) from the Source site.\nYou can modify how you receive notifications at My Workspace > Preferences."
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print (matches)
```

**Results**: `['http://www.source.sakaiproject.org/viewsvn/?view=rev&rev=39772', 'https://collab.sakaiproject.org/portal']`

Comment: Thanks @Ryszard Czech